# Null pointer exception due to driver instance is null in onTestFailureMethod

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

Need help on - I am getting null pointer exception in onTestFailure method. If any of my @Test method fails control goes to onTestFailure but driver is null in that method. my code is like -

```
import statements...
@Listeners(ScreenShot.class)
public class ScreenShot implements ITestListener{
    WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeClass
    public void launch(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\Jars\\Drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get("url");
    }

    @Test
    public void test1(){
        //driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("E@E.COM");
        System.out.println("Method1 begins");
        //some code here - exception occurs here
        System.out.println("Method ended");
    }

    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result){
        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);  //Getting exception here as driver is null
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:\\snaps\\"+result.getMethod().getMethodName()+".png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```

i am running this class by right click->run as testng.

Comment: make the webdriver static and try again.

Comment: yeah you can achieve your results by any of the ways spoken down by @niharika_neo...

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting a NullPointerException is because Testng creates a new instance of each listener. So that new instance has driver not initialized.

In your case, the object of Screenshot class running the @Test method and the instance of the Screenshot class as a  listener being invoked by TestNG is different.

There are couple of ways to solve this.

1. Move the code from onTestFailure to @AfterMethod with the ITestResult as the method argument.  Work on the result data to take screenshot.

   ```
   @AfterMethod
   public void afterMet(ITestResult res){
           if(res.isSuccess())
   ```
2. Make the driver as a global static.  - if you plan to run only sequential tests
3. Consider threadlocal if you plan to run parallely.